# Como listar mis bases de datos en EXCEL con VBA

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

estoy intentando profundizar más en la conexión desde VBA usando Excel contra MS SQL.

Todo bien con la conexión forzada poniendo todos los parametros en los datos de la macro (nombre del servidor, base de datos, etc.) Pero querría hacerlo algo más complejo.

¿Sería posible al inicio de la hoja excel, que en un combo se listaran las bases de datos del servidor? No consigo mas que errores y no sé si estoy perdiendo el tiempo.

Gracias.

Adjunto código

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim CMDStoredProc As ADODB.Command
Dim CnnConexion As ADODB.Connection
Dim RcsDatos As ADODB.Recordset

Dim CadConexion As String 'Cadena de conexión
Dim Row As Integer
Dim RecordsAffected As Long

'Cadena de conexión
Dim Servidor As String
Dim Usuario As String
Dim Contrasena As String
Dim BaseDatos As String

Servidor = "SOPORTE-SW1\A3ERP"
Usuario = "sa"
Contrasena = "1234"
BaseDatos = ""

' CadConexion = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" & Usuario & ";Pwd=" & Contrasena & ";Initial Catalog=" & BaseDatos & ";Data Source=" & Servidor & ""
CadConexion = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=" & Usuario & ";Pwd=" & Contrasena & ";Data Source=" & Servidor & ""

Set CnnConexion = New ADODB.Connection
Set RcsDatos = New ADODB.Recordset
Set CMDStoredProc = New ADODB.Command

'Establecemos comunicación con nuestro servidor SQL Server
Call CnnConexion.Open(CadConexion)

'Enlazamos nuestros objetos y definimos el procedimiento almacenado a ejecutar
CMDStoredProc.CommandType = adCmdText
Set CMDStoredProc.ActiveConnection = CnnConexion
CMDStoredProc.CommandText = "EXEC sp_helpdb"

'Creamos el parámetro del procedimiento almacenado
Call CMDStoredProc.Parameters.Append(CMDStoredProc.CreateParameter("PV_OPCION", DataTypeEnum.adChar, ParameterDirectionEnum.adParamInput, 10))

'Ejecutamos de Script
Set RcsDatos = CMDStoredProc.Execute(RecordsAffected, , ExecuteOptionEnum.adAsyncFetch)

'Recorremos el Recordset resultante para asignarlo a la celda en Excel
Row = 1
Do While Not RcsDatos.EOF
    Cells(Row, 2).Value = RcsDatos.Fields(0).Value
    Row = Row + 1
    RcsDatos.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

El error que me aparece es "No se ha definido el tipo definido por el usuario"

Comment: Hola lordmiaux. Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora y qué errores te han salido? Mira [ask]  para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por agregar el mensaje de error. ¿Puedes indicarnos en qué línea ocurre?

Comment: Justo en el arranque del método: Sub CommandButton1_Click(). Ahí me aparece coloreado en amarillo

Answer (score 1):

El error específico que recibes indica que te faltan referencias a las librerías necesarias para poder manipular ciertas clases.

Según tu código, lo más probable es que no hayas incluido una referencia a la librería ADO.

Para agregarlo, en el editor VBA, ve al menú `Tools --> References` (`Herramientas --> Referencias` en español?), y agrega la librería `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library`. Puede que encuentras varias versiones de esta librería en la lista. Usualmente puedes escoger el que tenga la versión más reciente.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona a la perfección